How can I align the logo image to the right side using CSS Flexbox?
How can I align the logo image to the right side using CSS Flexbox?

The .logo class is set to display: flex;, which turns its children into flex items.

justify-content: flex-end; aligns the flex items to the end of the container, pushing the logo image to the right.

align-items: center; centers the items vertically within the flex container.

margin-right: 20px; adds some margin to the right of the logo image to separate it from the navigation.




:root {
  --color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --bgcolor: rgb(160, 88, 196);
  --bbg: rgb(203, 194, 210);
  --boxmbg: rgb(65, 136, 65);
  --box1bg: rgb(240, 151, 149);
  --box2bg: rgb(76, 128, 218);
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--bbg);
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  /* margin: 10px; */
  display: flex;

  color: var(--color);
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.boxmain {
  margin-left: 10x;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128);
  margin: 60px;

  height: 70vh;
  background-color: var(--boxmbg);
}
.box1 {
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128); */
  margin: 10px;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: var(--box1bg);
}
.box2 {
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128); */
  margin: 5px;

  height: 65vh;
  width: 40%;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: var(--box2bg);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: -95.6%;
}
.box3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5vw;
  padding: 2vh;
}
.box3 h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.logo img {
  top: 70vh;
  position: fixed;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* padding-left: 90vw; */
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px red);
  width: 6vb;
}
<div class="logo">
  <img
    align="right" 
    src="https://searchmaro.in/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Untitled-design6-1.png"
    alt="HEllo"
  />
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxmain">
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      <h1>Thanks For Visiting Search Maro</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Repositioned the .logo div after the .box div, then added justify-content: flex-end; and align-items: center; to center the logo to the right side and vertically, and removed some unnecessary stuff.


:root {
  --color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --bgcolor: rgb(160, 88, 196);
  --bbg: rgb(203, 194, 210);
  --boxmbg: rgb(65, 136, 65);
  --box1bg: rgb(240, 151, 149);
  --box2bg: rgb(76, 128, 218);
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--bbg);
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  /* margin: 10px; */
  display: flex;

  color: var(--color);
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.boxmain {
  margin-left: 10x;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128);
  margin: 60px;

  height: 70vh;
  background-color: var(--boxmbg);
}
.box1 {
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128); */
  margin: 10px;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: var(--box1bg);
}
.box2 {
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgb(224, 237, 128); */
  margin: 5px;

  height: 65vh;
  width: 40%;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: var(--box2bg);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: -95.6%;
}
.box3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5vw;
  padding: 2vh;
}
.box3 h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.logo img {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px red);
  width: 100px; /* Adjust width as needed */
}
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxmain">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <h1>Thanks For Visiting Search Maro</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://searchmaro.in/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Untitled-design6-1.png" alt="HEllo" />
</div>



